redirect() (next/navigation) not working in nextJS + Supabase Auth
I'm trying to use Supabase Auth with NextJS. I'm following Next docs however the login action does not redirect to my route.
app/(auth)/_actions/login.ts
"use server";

import { createClient } from "@/app/_utils/supabase/server";
import { revalidatePath } from "next/cache";
import { redirect } from "next/navigation";

export async function login(formData: FormData) {
  const supabase = createClient();

  const data = {
    email: formData.get("email") as string,
    password: formData.get("password") as string,
  };

  const request = await supabase.auth.signInWithPassword(data);

  if (request.error) {
    redirect("/404");
  }
  console.log("Login successful, redirecting to /trips");
  revalidatePath("/", "layout");
  redirect("/trips");
}

This is my login action which is called from the login component. It works but it does not redirect.
app/(auth)/login/page.tsx
export default function Login() {
  return (
    <main className="h-full w-full flex flex-col justify-between items-center pt-56 pb-24">
      <form className="flex flex-col w-80" action={login}>
        <Input
          name="email"
          className="mb-5"
          fullWidth
          placeholder="Email"
          type="text"
        />
        <div className="w-full mb-5">
          <Input
            name="password"
            className="mb-1"
            fullWidth
            placeholder="Password"
            type="password"
          />
        </div>
        <Button type="submit" uppercase={true} filled={true}>
          Inicia sesión
        </Button>
      </form>
    </main>
  );
}

app/_utils/supabase/server.ts
import { createServerClient, type CookieOptions } from "@supabase/ssr";
import { cookies } from "next/headers";

export function createClient() {
  const cookieStore = cookies();

  return createServerClient(
    process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_URL!,
    process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_ANON_KEY!,
    {
      cookies: {
        getAll() {
          return cookieStore.getAll();
        },
        setAll(cookiesToSet) {
          try {
            cookiesToSet.forEach(({ name, value, options }) =>
              cookieStore.set(name, value, options)
            );
          } catch {
          }
        },
      },
    }
  );
}

It logs in - saves session - but it does not redirect when it logs in. It stays in the same page and all I get are 303 responses.

Not sure if you still have this problem. I was just going through the same issue today. I could pinpoint to the supbase authentication changing (either log in or out). I worked around it by handling the form and posting to a route rather than letting the form submit.
